# How can I render an Array nested in another Array with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am trying to create a currency converter and I want to show a list with the currency and the value. I am getting some data using **axios** from an API and my data looks like this:

```
Object {type: "li", key: "0", ref: null, props: Object, _owner: null…}
type: "li"
key: "0"
ref: null
props: Object
 children: Array[33]
 0: Object
  name: "AUD"
  value: 1.5167896679
 1: Object
 2: Object
```

...

When I try to map the data it is not showing anything:

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";

class Table extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      result: null,
      fromCurrency: "USD",
      currencyList: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getCoinTypes();
  }

  getCoinTypes() {
    let currency = [];

    axios
      .get(
        `https://alt-exchange-rate.herokuapp.com/latest?base=${
          this.state.fromCurrency
        }`
      )
      .then(response => {
        currency.push(
          Object.keys(response.data.rates).map(k => ({
            name: k,
            value: response.data.rates[k]
          }))
        );

        this.setState({
          currencyList: currency
        });

        this.state.currencyList.map((val, index) => {
          return console.log(<li key={index}>{val}</li>);
        });
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <table className="table table-sm bg-light mt-4">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col" />
            <th scope="col" className="text-right pr-4 py-2">
              5.00
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {this.state.currencyList.map((val, index) => {
            <tr key={index}>
              <th>{index}</th>
              <th>{val}</th>
            </tr>;
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
}

export default Table;
```

What I am want to achieve is e.g:

- USD     1.00
- AUD     1.95

and so on...

The link to [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-props-practice-t8dtu)

Comment: You need a render function to get your data into the browser. Is React not throwing errors about your class?

Comment: I am working in codesanbox, and using console.log to see how it looks

Comment: Can you attach a link to your answer so we have all the code to work with?

Comment: Sure! this is my link: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-props-practice-t8dtu

Comment: Can I recommend adding that link to your original post? It helps us dense stack exchange users.

Comment: I have added the link to sandbox

Comment: Is this what you're wanting? https://codesandbox.io/s/react-props-practice-mf1mo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you needed? https://codesandbox.io/s/react-props-practice-tsvbu

If yes, what I did was to save the currency "label" (USD, AUD, etc) and it's "value" (1.00, 1.69, etc)

Comment: Throwing an error for non-unique keys. I suggest concatenating the array index with the currency label for a key.

Comment: Updated sandbox. Fixed error for non-unique keys. Cleaned up Table.jsx

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working code sandbox

https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-props-practice-94t49?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Changed this on line 60 of Table.jsx

```js
          {this.state.currencyList.map((val, index) => {
            return (
              <tr key={index}>
                <th>{index}</th>
                <th>{val.value}</th>
              </tr>
            );
          })}
```